# in laravel, how do you use an @if statement in a view to verify a database condition so that it hides/shows some content based on the condition

Tags: php, laravel

this is the home.blade.php file

```
   @foreach($userview as $userview){
                    @if($userview = [{"role_code": "auv_recommend"}]){
                        <center>
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu aria-expanded="false">AUV</button>
                                    <div class="dropright dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(14px, 60px, 0px);">
                                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a tabindex=" -1" href="create">CREATE</a></button>
                                            <button class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle test1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">VIEW</button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropright">
                                                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a tabindex="-1" href="pendinglistSH">Awaiting Approval</a></button>
                                                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button"><a tabindex=" -1" href="reports">Reports</a></button>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </center>}
```

this is the controller for returning the home view created as a standalone for authentication

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index(){

        $userview = Session::get('userview');
        return view('home')->with($userview);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

this is the login controller responsible for authenticating a user and inserting data into a session

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use App\User;
use App\userprofile;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function login(Request $request) {

        $request->validate( [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password'=> 'required',
        ]);

        // $input = $request->all();
        // $input['password'] = md5($input['password']);

        $execsys_data = array(
            'username' => $request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        );


        if (Auth::attempt($execsys_data)) {
            $request->session()->put('authenticated',true);
            $request->session()->put('username');
            $request->session()->put('section');
            $request->session()->put('firstname');

            //     SELECT role_code FROM `userprofiles`

            // inner join roleprofiles on roleprofiles.profile_code = userprofiles.profile_code

            // WHERE username = 'sumbu'
            $userview = userprofile::where([
                ['userprofiles.username', '=', Auth::user()->username]
            ])
            ->join('roleprofiles', 'roleprofiles.profile_code', '=', 'userprofiles.profile_code')
            ->get('roleprofiles.role_code');

            return($userview);


            // $request->session()->put('userview', $userview);

            // if ($request->session()->has($userview))

            return redirect('home')->with($userview);
                    // echo($userview);

            }
        else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Credentials');
        }
    }

    // public function create()
    // {
    //     return view('pages.create');
    // }


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        // $this->middleware('guest:create')->except('logout');

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            // $this->user = Auth::roleprofile();
        //    $this->username = Auth::guard('api')->username;
            return $next($request);

        });

    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->user['remember_token'];
    }

    public function getUserview()
    {
        return $this->userview;
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
        {
        // $request->session()->forget('authenticated');
        // $request->session()->forget('username');
        // $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect('auth.login');

    }



}
```

also how do I get the column value only without returning an array so that I can use it to check my condition, i tried inserting the variable $userview into a session so that I could get it to go to another controller and try and call the variable from the home controller but it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can fetch the desired data in the method that is responsible for serving your view. If this would be your home page for example, that would be `index()`.

Example:

```
public function index(){

   $userview = Session::get('userview');

   // Example data
   $yourData = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();

   // Pass an array as second argument to view to pass more data, or you 
   // can chain ->with calls
   return view('greetings', ['userview' => $userview, 'yourdata' => $user]);
}
```

You can then use both `userview` and `yourdata` in your `index` view.

Comment: i think i tried something similar to the $userview in your answer when i was trying to get the session data but the problem is the session is bieng taken from the Login Controller above and i was trying to get it into the other controller before returning it with the method returning the view

Comment: ```
  $userview = Session::get('userview');
        return view('home')->with($userview);
```
maybe i messed up the return with part i dont know

Comment: thanks { @Fabian Tjoe A on } your solution helped me so much

Comment: @KASVDOLLAERHIT good to hear! if my answer solved your question, please mark it as solved :)